# Cant access http public IP Adress with google cloud compute engine

Tags: iptables, firewall, apache2, cloud, google

What did i do so far? I tried restarting apache2, i tried to see if the firewall was open but still nothing seems to work. Can someone help me, the public ip address suddenly changed and from that moment it broke everything before that it worked fine.

Comment: Have you updated DNS to point at the new IP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't even access the public IP. But yes i also updated the DNS